# How to manage multiple spiders in a scrapy project

Tags: scrapy

I am new to scrapy but have successfully created a fairly sophisticated spider. Now I want to add a few more to the same project. I tried copying my working spider and editing it to work with another target but I am getting all sorts of global variable errors. I have tried "scrapy crawl my_new_spider" but is seems that all spiders are being initiated. What gives? Should just add a new class in the existing spider? This doesn't seem scalable... any pointers would be appreciated. The docs got me pretty far but I am stumbling now.

Many thanks!

Comment: Code?  Very helpful.

Comment: global my_var = True

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand from your question, best way to add more spider is by adding new class in a new file under the spiders folder, 
try to give separate names to each of the spider. Using this structure you can share your items.py, settings.py etc for all spiders under same project.

```
tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg
    tutorial/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            __init__.py
            spider1.py
            spider2.py
            ......
```

and in spider1 and spider2 you can set names accordingly, like

```
    name= "spider1" and name="spider2"
```

so that you can run your spiders as

```
    scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Comment: Thanks Tasawer! That is exactly what I have done but the errors remain.I don't understand why if I am specifying the spider that I want initiated that it is throwing an error in the other spider. Its almost like scrapy is trying to initiate all spiders and not the one that I am specifying. I can change the global variable name but I feel that this is simply a symptom of improper setup and/or configuration. Do I need to do anything special in the settings? Maybe my class is static?

Comment: After fixing a minor syntax error, your suggestion helped me solve the root of my problem. Thx.